# How to use print method

Tags: vb6

I have a file called `worker.dat`, and in that file, a list of information is stored as variables "Income","Promotion", "Age" etc.
And I want to read that information from the file and print on the screen.

So I used

```
Open App.Path & "worker.DAT" For Input As #1
```

and using the `Print` method, printed the information.

However for the sake of emphasis, I want to print some information in a bigger size and in different font etc.

So I wrote this.

```
Printer.FontSize = 16  
Printer.Print "Income = "; Income
```

However this didn't work. Does anyone how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you set the font to a scalable font like Arial?

Comment: Print to the screen or to the form? You mention both.

Answer (score 0):

Set the size on the font object:

```
Dim pt As Long

With Printer.Font
    pt = .Size

    Printer.Print "default text"

    .Size = 16
    Printer.Print "larger text"

    .Size = pt
    .Bold = True
    Printer.Print "bold ";
    .Bold = False
    Printer.Print "in default size"

    Printer.EndDoc
End With
```